# Yellow selection outline not appearing in solid 3D view

Tags: 3d-view

I am sure I broke something: The yellow selection outline appears in the 3D viewport in material and texture modes, but not in solid any more:

[image]

... and this is because...?

The behavior persists if I append the object into a new Blender file.

The behavior persists if I replace the existing material with a single diffuse shader node; thanks to @Leander for suggestion, however.

The behavior does not occut if the object's material is assigned to default cube. @Leander

Answer (score 1):

Blender doesn't show the outline for transparent objects in the viewport.

Remove transparency in your material to make the outline visible again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks... but no transparency on object.

Comment: @Leader Behavior exists even with a single plain diffuse node.

Comment: @rcgauer I guess sharing [your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) is necessary then, you could replace your mesh geometry with a cube beforehand.

Comment: Behavior does NOT occur if I assign that material to default cube, which is interesting. And highlighting works as intended in Wire, Texture and Material modes. Interesting. @Leander